# Initialize a document and mark it as "unchanged"

Tags: macos, swift, core-data, document

I'm trying to write my first Core Data driven document-oriented OSX application in Swift, as I want to get a bit more into Mac programming. The documents should be saved as XML files only, which I've managed to successfully configure.

The problem is that I want to pre-add some information to the document upon initializing without really "modifying" the document. The information is just required and should be in the document, but if the user creates and right away closes a document he should not be asked to save.

I've defined my Core Data data model and I've created `NSManagedObject` subclasses from my model. In my document's `init` method I'm doing this:

```
override init() {
    super.init()

    // Add your subclass-specific initialization here.
    let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyItem", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! MyItem;
    newItem.descriptionText = "Item number 1";
    newItem.itemNumber = 1;
}
```

This does add a new item to my document and when I save and re-load I can verify that the item is there. However, doing it this way, the document is marked "dirty" and upon closing it, the user is asked to save the changes.

How would I perform an initialization of my data model without actually marking the document as edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I managed to solve this to work in my case. First of all, I moved my intialization code to

```
convenience init?(type typeName: String, error outError: NSErrorPointer)
```

Then I temporarily suspend the undo-functionality:

```
self.managedObjectContext.processPendingChanges();
self.undoManager.disableUndoRegistration();
```

After I make my changes I re-enable the undo-functionality:

```
self.managedObjectContext.processPendingChanges();
self.undoManager.enableUndoRegistration();
```

This has worked well so far.